# how can i pass value from python to select tag on html form?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am developing web application using python flask. As a part of this there is one patient update page here it has fields like `patient id`, `name`, `age`, etc and two buttons get and update. User has to click get button after entering patient id to fill all the remaining fields. For this I wrote a function which retrieves data of that patient from database then I send data(all variables and values) by using flask render template. Html form is displaying values in text fields only but I want to display values for select and textarea also.input tag has value attribute so it is printing value what I passed but there is no value attribute for textarea and select so how can I pass val.

Please help me to solve this

**python code**

```
@app.route('/getPatient')
def getPatient():
    pid=request.args.get('PID')
    print(pid)
    con = sqlite3.connect("sample.db")  
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row  
    cur = con.cursor()  
    cur.execute("select * from PatientStore WHERE PATIENT_ID=?",(pid,))  
    rows = cur.fetchall()
   
    for i in rows:
        ssnid=i[0]
        name=i[2]
        address=i[3]
        age=i[4]
        doa=i[5]
        rtype=i[6]
        city=i[7]
        state=i[8]
        status=[9]
    
    return render_template("updatePatient.html",pid=pid,ssnid=ssnid,name=name,address=address,age=age,doa=doa,rtype=rtype,city=city,state=state,status=status)
```

I entered patientid then i clicked get button later it displays all the text fields except select option how can i pass value to it to display like text fields(name,date of joining etc:
[image]

```html
<form action="{{url_for('getPatient')}}">
<div class="container">
<h3 >Update Patient </h3>
<label class="labelid"><b>Patient ID</b></label>
<input id="field_PID" title="PID must not be blank and contain only 9 numbers." type="text" required pattern="[0-9]{9,}" name="PID" value="{{pid}}" required>&emsp;&emsp
<button style="border-radius: 12px;background color:black;color:white;height:25px;width:100px;" type="submit" value='Submit'>Get</a></button><br>
<br></form>
<form action="{{url_for('index')}}">
<label><b>Patient Name</b></label>
<input id="field_PName" title="name must not be blank and contain only letters." type="text"  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+{2,}" name="PName" value="{{name}}"><br><br>
<label><b>Patient Age</b></label>
<input id="field_PAge" title="Patient Age must not be blank and contain only numbers." type="text"  pattern="[0-9]{1,3}" name="PAge" value="{{age}}"><br>
<br>
<label><b>Date of Admission</b></label>
<input id="field_DOA" title="DOA must be in the format ccyy/mm/dd." type="text"  pattern="([12]\d{3}/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))" name="DOA" value="{{doa}}" ><br><br>
<div id="label"></div>
<label><b>Type of bed</b></label>
<select class="selector1" name="BType" id="BType">
<option disabled selected value=""> Select</option>
<option value="General">General Ward</option>
<option value="Shared">Semi Sharing</option>
<option value="Single">Single Room</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<label><b>Address</b></label>
<textarea  class="textarea1" id="Address" name="Address" value="{{address}}" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea ><br/><br/>
</form>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: please clean up your question content and formatting.

Comment: are you running this using "python app.py"

Comment: yes iam running using python app.py